# How to plot heatmap on a image using plotly in javascript?

Tags: javascript, plotly, heatmap, plotly.js

How to plot heatmap on an image using the Plotly.js,

main aim is to the plot the heatmap on the mobile view.

for example, these are some data points.

```
 var data: any = [
   {
     z: [[1, 20, 30], [20, 1, 60], [30, 60, 1], [782, 452, 29], [452, 128, 57]],
     type: 'heatmap'
   }
 ];
```

[image: 1280x720]

some useful link
https://plotly.com/javascript/heatmaps/

Comment: Please clarify - Do you want to superimpose/overlay the heatmap on the  image?

Comment: @SumedhPatkar yes overlay is fine.